# about the definition of small or micro RTOS

Tags: rtos

I am confused about small or micro RTOS, is it equivalent to RTOS with micro kernel?
And what are other types of RTOS except micro RTOS?

Answer (score 0):

Where or in what context have you seen these terms?

They do not have any specific technical meaning, I would suggest that they are informal descriptions of the memory footprint required to run them.

Look at it this way uC/OS-II for example is small, while QNX is large (for an RTOS), everything is on a spectrum.

Comment: small or micro RTOS usually do not support virtual memory.  A micro kernel usually includes the ability to define tasks, mutexes, semaphores, real-time preemptive scheduler, context switching, interrupt service routines etc.

Comment: @MarkHendrickson:  That looks remarkably like an answer rather than a comment.  Unless you are disagreeing with me that these terms have no specific meaning.  I asked for context which was not forthcoming.  I don't think these terms have a "definition" without knowing who has used them, and in what context.  While it is true perhaps that QNX is large (albeit scalable) *and* supports (requires in fact) an MMU, VxWorks is also a "large" RTOS by most reckoning, and does not need an MMU, its size is more about the provision of file-systems, network stacks, and device drivers.